# Using awk, eliminate any empty fields in a file and print in proper format

Tags: bash, awk

how to use awk on the following file named "awk.txt" and print all fields in proper length of space or tab length between.

```
# cat /root/awk.txt
abc hij     klm
 def  pqr   hij
mmm fgf     hgt
  yyt   ghf   jkw
```

I wanted to use awk on this and print in the following proper format.

```
abc   hij   klm
def   pqr   hij
mmm   fgf   hgt
yyt   ghf   jkw
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `column` command from coreutils:

```
column -t file
```

In this special case, where all entries have the same length, the following awk command would do the trick as well, however `column` can do the job even if the entries have different length:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='  ' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This line of awk will format the output using printf ([documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html))

```
awk '{printf "%3s\t%3s\t%3s\n",$1,$2,$3}' awk.txt
```

If you want to strip the first line starting with `#`

```
awk '!/^#/{printf "%3s\t%3s\t%3s\n",$1,$2,$3}'
```

Comment: Please, try to add some explanation to your answer, it will be more clear and useful

Comment: Thank you very much, that gives proper output(I checked). But can you give a brief description on what these two awk commands actually does to print it in proper format.